# Custom check box image with asp.net/MVC Razor/Telerik

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, telerik

I using asp.net MVC3 with Razor and I have Telerik controls available.
Is there some way to use MVC HTML helpers or Telerik MVC controls to make a custom check box that works with images?

Such as - 
instead of having a box with or without a check mark, we could use two light bulb images that work as the check box. 
A user would click the "off" light bulb image which would switch to the "on" image to indicate checked, and a user would click the "on" light bulb which would switch to the "off" image to indicate unchecked.

(FYI - I found an example using css, that looks promising for anyone else looking for a css solution -

http://www.wufoo.com/2011/06/13/custom-radio-buttons-and-checkboxes/)

Thanks!